# How to calculate FMCW Radar Chirp STFT?

Tags: fft, stft, radar

[image: spectrogram]I have received signal from FMCW Radar which is of the shape [128x64] = [Number of samples per chirp x Number of chirps per cycle] and i want to calculate the stft
i am calculating it with stft command and for that using vectorized data.[1x8192]

```
fs = 1000e3;
win = blackman(64,'periodic');
[S,F,T] = stft(data,fs,'Window',win,'OverlapLength',60,'FFTLength',256);
S = abs(S);
imagesc(T,F,S);
colorbar;
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Frequency');
zlabel('Amplitude');
title('Spectrogram');
```

From this i am getting the same plot for every cycle. Is this approach correct or do i have to calculate the stft separetely for every chirp?
If my approach appraoch is correct what does this stft tells me?
[Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ArImf4MiUt8T49LlY6RK7DdlGjv-G7uC/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: that image is inaccessible to the public. Please **edit** your question and use the "image" button in the editor to upload your picture.

Comment: @MarcusMüller please see

Comment: very nice, thank you!

Comment: so, it's hard to say whether this is correct. Is it what you expect?

Comment: i can't make any judgement. That is the question, i uploaded the data

Comment: I mean, is there a radar target that moves? What exactly is "signal from FMCW radar": is it complex baseband, or already de-chirped/beat frequency signal?

Comment: Yes target moves, and the signal is IQ in my understanding (received chirp) . get 8192 values per cycle [128x 64]

Comment: ok, then we both agree that the judgement is that the plot shouldn't look like this. However, I'm not sure that `stft` works in the direction you want to: does things get better when you transpose `data`?